# Ignore parent element in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<RootItem>
  <Items>
    <Item />
    <Item />
    <Item />
  </Items>
  <Values>
    <Value />
    <Value />
    <Value />
  </Values>
  <AnotherItem />
</RootItem>
```

I'm using Trang to translate this into a .xsd schema, and using xjc to translate the schema into annotated Java classes (that work smoothly with jaxB to marshal and unmarshall my documents)  My only problem is that xjc gives me these classes:

- RootItem.java
- Items.java
- Item.java
- Values.java
- Value.java
- ObjectFactory.java (required by JaxB)

I don't want a "Items" or a "Values" class.  How do I format my schema to tell it to ignore the parent element and just make a "List items" object in my RootItem class?

What I want:

- RootItem.java
- Item.java
- Value.java
- ObjectFactory.java (required by JaxB)

Thanks!

Edit:  Here's the schema generated by Trang:

```
<xs:element name="RootItem">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Items"/>
      <xs:element ref="Values"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="AnotherItem" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Items">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Item"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Values">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Value"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Show us the XML schema, and we'll advise how to change it.

Comment: I added the XML schema that Trang currently generates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always start from Java classes.  You can use @XmlElementWrapper to get the grouping elements "Items" and "Values".

Note:
JAXB does not require the object factory.  JAXB can leverage metadata on a class like ObjectFactory that is annotated with @XmlRegistry.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'm still curious if there's a way to specify wrapper elements in a schema, but this solved my problem.  You're the best!